# Some methods of my application could not be found

Tags: go

I am new to GoLang and I've been trying to create a package which should store the information about the application.

I have the following structure for the `Application`

```golang
type Application struct {
    Environment     environment.ApplicationEnvironment
    Vendor          string
    Name            string
    Version         version.VersionDescriptor
    JsonLog         bool
    configuration   *Config
    micro           *GoMicro
}
```

I also have these two methods, the issue I am experiencing is that whenever I try to call the second method, it throws the following error

```sh
.\main.go:11:17: app.GetEnvironmentPrefix undefined (type *application.Application has no field or method GetEnvironmentPrefix)
```

Here are those two methods I am talking about:

```golang
// Get application environment type
func (application *Application) GetEnvironmentType() environment.EnvironmentType {
    return application.GetEnvironmentDetails().Type
}

// Get application environment prefix
func (application *Application) GetEnvironmentPrefix() string {
    str := strings.Replace(application.GetVendor() + "_" + application.GetName(), " ", "_", -1)
    str = strings.Replace(str, ".", "_", -1)
    return strings.ToUpper(str)
}
```

The only thing I've done before implementing the second method is that I've ran `go module init`.

I've tried removing all fetched modules, I've tried `go clean (with many options)`, however, none of the methods implemented after the `go module init` work.

I had to do the `go module init` because `go-micro` was throwing lots of errors otherwise.

My environment is:

- **Operating System:** Windows 10 1909
- **Go Version:** 1.13.4 windows/amd64
- **IDE:** GoLand (it also manages the GOPATH, there is no access to `go` outside the IDE)

P.S. This is how the `main.go` looks like

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/USERNAME_OMITTED/service/application"
)

func main() {
    app := application.CreateApplication()
    fmt.Println(app.GetEnvironmentType()) // Works just fine
    fmt.Println(app.GetEnvironmentPrefix()) // Does not work

}
```

P.P.S. Maybe it will help, here is the complete structure for the `application.go` file inside the `repository/application/application.go`

```golang
package application

import (
    format "fmt"
    "github.com/USERNAME_OMITTED/service/context"
    "github.com/USERNAME_OMITTED/service/environment"
    "github.com/USERNAME_OMITTED/service/helpers"
    "github.com/USERNAME_OMITTED/service/log"
    "github.com/USERNAME_OMITTED/service/version"
    "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"
    "strings"
)

type Application struct {
    Environment     environment.ApplicationEnvironment
    Vendor          string
    Name            string
    Version         version.VersionDescriptor
    JsonLog         bool
    configuration   *Config
    micro           *GoMicro
}

// Create new application
func CreateApplication() *Application {
    var Vendor string = helpers.GetEnvironmentVariable(
        "APPLICATION_VENDOR",
        "USERNAME_OMITTED",
    )

    var Name string = helpers.GetEnvironmentVariable(
        "APPLICATION_NAME",
        helpers.AppendTimestampToString("New Application"),
    )

    var Version string = helpers.GetEnvironmentVariable(
        "APPLICATION_VERSION",
        "1.0.0.0",
    )

    application := &Application {
        Vendor:         normalizeVendorName(Vendor),
        Name:           normalizeApplicationName(Name),
        Environment:    environment.GetApplicationEnvironment(),
        JsonLog:        false,
    }

    err := application.Version.UnmarshalText([]byte(Version))
    if err != nil {
        application.Version = version.DefaultVersion
    }

    application.initializeLogger()

    context.WithValue("application", application)
    return application
}

// Force application to output log in JSON format
func (application *Application) ForceJsonLog() {
    application.JsonLog = true
    application.initializeLogger()
}

// Get application vendor name
func (application *Application) GetVendor() string {
    return application.Vendor
}

// Get application name
func (application *Application) GetName() string {
    return application.Name
}

// Get application version descriptor
func (application *Application) GetVersionDescriptor() version.VersionDescriptor {
    return application.Version
}

// Get application version represented as string
func (application *Application) GetVersion() string {
    return application.GetVersionDescriptor().String()
}

// Get application environment full details
func (application *Application) GetEnvironmentDetails() environment.ApplicationEnvironment {
    return application.Environment
}

// Get application environment name
func (application *Application) GetEnvironmentName() string {
    return application.GetEnvironmentDetails().Name
}

// Get application environment type
func (application *Application) GetEnvironmentType() environment.EnvironmentType {
    return application.GetEnvironmentDetails().Type
}

// Get application environment prefix
func (application *Application) GetEnvironmentPrefix() string {
    str := strings.Replace(application.GetVendor() + "_" + application.GetName(), "-", "_", -1)
    str = strings.Replace(str, ".", "_", -1)
    return strings.ToUpper(str)
}

// Get service name for the application
func (application *Application) GetServiceName() string {
    return format.Sprintf("%s.%s_%s-%s",
        application.GetVendor(),
        application.GetName(),
        application.GetVersion(),
        strings.ToLower(application.GetEnvironmentName()),
    )
}

// Initialize application configuration
func (application *Application) InitializeConfiguration() error {
    if application.configuration == nil {
        application.configuration = &Config{}
    }
    return application.configuration.Initialize(application)
}

// Initialize application as Go Micro Service
func (application *Application) InitializeGoMicroService() error {
    microService := &GoMicro{}
    err := microService.Initialize(application)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    application.micro = microService
    return nil
}

// Initialize application logger
func (application *Application) initializeLogger() {
    logger := logrus.New()
    var customFields = logrus.Fields{}

    if application.JsonLog || application.Environment.Type == environment.Production {
        logger.SetFormatter(&logrus.JSONFormatter{
            FieldMap: logrus.FieldMap {
                logrus.FieldKeyMsg:     "message",
                logrus.FieldKeyTime:    "timestamp",
            },
        })
        customFields = logrus.Fields{
            "application": logrus.Fields{
                "vendor": application.GetVendor(),
                "name": application.GetName(),
                "version": application.GetVersion(),
                "environment": strings.ToLower(application.GetEnvironmentName()),
            },
            "service": application.GetServiceName(),
        }
    } else {
        logger.SetFormatter(&logrus.TextFormatter{
            FieldMap: logrus.FieldMap{
                logrus.FieldKeyMsg:     "message",
                logrus.FieldKeyTime:    "timestamp",
            },
        })
        customFields = logrus.Fields{
            "service": application.GetServiceName(),
        }
    }

    log.SetLogger(logger.WithFields(customFields))
}


// Normalize Application Vendor Name
func normalizeVendorName(Vendor string) string {
    var newName string = strings.ToLower(Vendor)
    return newName
}

// Normalize Application Name
func normalizeApplicationName(Name string) string {
    var newName string = strings.ToLower(Name)
    newName = strings.ReplaceAll(newName, " ", "-")
    return newName
}
```

Comment: What is your module name in go.mod? Did you push this code to github? It might be pulling the application package from github, not from your local.

Comment: @BurakSerdar i have not pushed it to github yet, it is on local machine just inside the `src` directory with the respective naming rules. The name of the module is `module github.com/USERNAME_OMITTED/service`

Comment: The program at https://play.golang.org/p/fID2dT0NQiA compiles the line in question. I commented out or deleted all unrelated code.  What's different?

Comment: @CeriseLimón that is the problem, i have no idea why it ignores the changes i make to the `application.go` file, hence why i am asking for help. As for me it seems like there is a cached version of that file somewhere, and there should be none since i've tried to completely remove all modules

Comment: @IvanZhivolupov can you try building this outside the IDE?

Comment: You mentioned that `application.go` is inside `repository/application/application.go` although in your main func you are importing "github.com/USERNAME_OMITTED/service/application". Are you sure you're importing the same package?

Answer (score 0):

In your main.go, you're importing:

```
    "github.com/USERNAME_OMITTED/service/application"
```

But you mention that `repository/application/application.go` is the location that the application package is located. It sounds like you need to change the import statement to just:

```
    "github.com/USERNAME_OMITTED/application"
```